# move multiple files in a folder

Tags: php

I have a for loop for upload image. if i will upload an image and the number of resize image should be move on a folder. but my problem is if it only move the original image not the resize image. how can i move the resize image into a folder

```
move_uploaded_file($_FILES['image']['tmp_name'],'uploads/'.$_FILES['image']['name']);
for ($i=1; $i <=$resize ; $i++){
    $new = $album.$i."_".$target;
    $targetWidth = round($temp_width * $percentage);
    $targetHeight = round($temp_height * $percentage);

    $targetImage = imagecreatetruecolor($targetWidth, $targetHeight);
    $image = imagecreatefromstring(file_get_contents($target));
    imagejpeg($targetImage,$new,80);

    $temp_height = $targetHeight;
    $temp_width = $targetWidth;
}
```

only the original image is move and it does not do the resizing of the image. but if i will remove the `move_uploaded_file($_FILES['image']['tmp_name'],'uploads/'.$_FILES['image']['name']);` all result are there but not in the folder

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`imagejpeg` accepts 3 parameters. The resource image (the image you just created by resizing it), the filename (how and where to store the image) and the quality.
So you need to look at the second parameter. You called it `$new` which has the variable `$album` in it. If you set that to the location (folder) you want it to be it should work just fine.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagejpeg.php